# SQLilte query much slower through RSqlite than sqlite3 command-line interface

Tags: sqlite, r

I'm using the RSQLite package to make queries to a local SQLite database, and for some queries the RSQLite interface is quite slow.

As a specific example, the following query takes under one second to run using the sqlite3 command-line utility:

```
$ sqlite3 data/svn.db
SQLite version 3.7.5
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> select count(distinct svn_path.revision)  FROM src INNER JOIN svn_path ON src.filename=svn_path.path;
5039
```

But the equivalent query in R takes a little over two minutes and uses 100% of one of my CPUs:

```
> library(RSQLite)
Loading required package: DBI
> con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="data/svn.db")
> dbGetQuery(con, "select count(distinct svn_path.revision)  FROM src INNER JOIN svn_path ON src.filename=svn_path.path")
  count(distinct svn_path.revision)
1                              5039
```

Why is the performance so much slower through the R interface?

Note that I'm using R64 2.10.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.6.

Comment: Are you sure the query wasn't just cached on the server when you ran it via the command line?

Comment: @Daniel Dickison: SQLite has no server.

Comment: Maybe the RSQLite library does not the same engine version than the shell (3.7.5).

Comment: Whoops, good point.  I was thinking of MySQL for some reason.

Comment: What matters is the version of RSQLite you have.  Your version of R seems to be over a year old so if your RSQLite is just as old it could be a much older engine (eg, 3.6.4) as suggested by Benoit.  Out of desperation you could try swapping the table order if src and svn_path are very different in size (# of rows) eg `select count(distinct svn_path.revision) FROM svn_path INNER JOIN src ON src.filename=svn_path.path`.  If that makes it run faster, they're using different query plans.

Comment: Try running EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN for your query both from R and from the command line to see if they differ.

Comment: @Tony Lee: Upgrading R addressed the problem. If you respond with an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What matters is the version of RSQLite you have. Your version of R seems to be over a year old so if your RSQLite is just as old it could be a much older engine (eg, 3.6.4) as suggested by Benoit.